# Why does chown reset/remove the SUID bit and reset capabilities?

Tags: linux, permissions, acl, chown, capabilities

This command:

```bash
sudo chown -R root:root directory
```

will remove the SUID bit and reset all capabilities for *files*. I wonder why it's done silently and it's not mentioned in the man page. Weirdly the GUID bit is not removed. And it doesn't matter who the file or directory belonged to prior to running this command.

Also SUID/GUID bits are *not* removed for *directories* (thought they are useless in this case).

Presumably it's done in the name of security but to me it must not be done silently.

This gets even worse:

```bash
$ setcap cap_sys_rawio,cap_sys_nice=+ep test
$ getcap -v test 
test cap_sys_rawio,cap_sys_nice=ep

$ chown -c -v -R 0:0 .
ownership of './test' retained as root:root
ownership of '.' retained as root:root

$  getcap -v test 
test
```

The SUID bit for the `test` file is removed completely silently. It's as if the command is doing a lot more than requested.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [chown removes setuid bit: bug or feature?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53665/chown-removes-setuid-bit-bug-or-feature)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The permissions and capability sets aren’t cleared by the `chown` utility, they’re cleared by [the `chown` system call](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chown.2.html) (on Linux):

> When the owner or group of an executable file is changed by an
> unprivileged user, the `S_ISUID` and `S_ISGID` mode bits are cleared.
> POSIX does not specify whether this also should happen when root
> does the `chown()`; the Linux behavior depends on the kernel
> version, and since Linux 2.2.13, root is treated like other
> users.  In case of a non-group-executable file (i.e., one for
> which the `S_IXGRP` bit is not set) the `S_ISGID` bit indicates
> mandatory locking, and is not cleared by a `chown()`.
>
> When the owner or group of an executable file is changed (by any
> user), all capability sets for the file are cleared.

As alluded to above, this is partially [specified by POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/chown.html):

> Unless *chown* is invoked by a process with appropriate privileges, the set-user-ID and set-group-ID bits of a regular file shall be cleared upon successful completion; the set-user-ID and set-group-ID bits of other file types may be cleared.

If it were to inform the user about this, the `chown` utility would have to explicitly check for further changes made to files’ metadata when it invokes the `chown` function.

As far as the rationale is concerned, I suspect it’s to reduce the potential for gotchas for the system administrator — `chown root:root` on Linux can be considered as safe, even if a user prepared a setuid binary ahead of time.

[The GNU `chown` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chown.1.html) doesn’t mention this behaviour, but as is often the case with GNU software, the man page documents the utility only partially; its [“SEE ALSO”](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chown.1.html#SEE_ALSO) section points to [the system call documentation](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chown.2.html) (which is admittedly overkill for most users) and [the info page](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/chown-invocation.html), which does describe this behaviour:

> The `chown` command sometimes clears the set-user-ID or set-group-ID permission bits. This behavior depends on the policy and functionality of the underlying `chown` system call, which may make system-dependent file mode modifications outside the control of the `chown` command. For example, the `chown` command might not affect those bits when invoked by a user with appropriate privileges, or when the bits signify some function other than executable permission (e.g., mandatory locking). When in doubt, check the underlying system behavior.

(I’m limiting this to Linux based on your tags on the question; since Linux restricts owner changes to privileged processes, there are fewer security implications than on some other Unix-style systems. See [explanation on chown(1) POSIX spec](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/137086/86440) for details.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but you've not answered why the man page fails to mention this. I cannot be the first person to encounter this behavior. And why the GUID bit and directories are left intact? I just don't like how it's all handled. I thought UNIX/POSIX was more "open" and "straightforward" than Windows where many things are under the veil of secrecy or/and compatibility only Microsoft engineers know about. As a user I will definitely not dig so deep as to delve on chown syscall documentation.

Comment: On some systems, the suid and sgid bits on directories do something unrelated to what they do on executables (on others the suid bit does nothing; I'm not sure about sgid.) They are essentially just repurposed. Since their function on directories is totally unrelated to their function on files, it's treated differently. https://superuser.com/questions/1013867/suid-bit-on-directories